# SPEAK UI - Insert Custom Dropdown to Sitecore InsertLinkViaTreeDialog

Tags: speak

Trying to add a dropdown control to store values from location - /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Goals. But the dropdown control does not have the datasource values.

From the Search log , I can see that SearchDataDataSource/QueryDataSource Renderings in SPEAK UI are hardcoded to use the Sitecore_core_index and the items which I need are in the Master DB/Index.

Can some one confirm the same or point to some documentation on filling dropdown/combo-box renderings in Speak UI with data from Master DB.

I have followed this blogs for the initial setup - https://www.akshaysura.com/2017/04/07/dont-speak-i-know-just-what-youre-saying-sitecore-speak-customize-general-link-with-nofollow-checkbox/

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you find an answer to your question by chance? working on a similar requirement now